# Truffle console call contract without ABI (Ganache Forked BSC)

Tags: truffle, ganache-cli

So I started Ganache-cli with -f option to fork the BSC (ETH FORK), and in the truffle console I want to interact with some smart contracts that are not mine nor I deployed them, how can I interact with them without having the ABI of the given contract?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You need an ABI to interact with a contract.

Comment: How could I get an ABI from a contract thats not mine? Downloading it and compiling?

Comment: You just can't! If the person did not make the ABI public, there is no way to have it. You can try decompiling the bytecode, but good luck if you can understand anything...

Comment: How could I find the ABI if its public?